# What is the proper Table publication format for an IEEE Xplore publication?

Tags: tables, captions, ieeetran, ieeeconf

I am finishing to write a scientific paper for an **IEEE Xplore** (I am not sure if IEEE Xplore and IEEE are the same organization - Publisher by the way will be IEEE) publication and wanted to ask a clarification about where the caption should properly and officially be positioned?

I have a Table so far with the caption on top as below:

[image]

Or should the caption should be on the bottom of the table as below? :

[image]

Which brings me to a couple more follow-up questions such as:

1. Does that matter if the table is in half column or if it stretches across the two columns occupying the whole space? Is there any implication with the caption?
2. What if I take a picture of a table, say on excel, and put the image of the table in the paper? Does that still count as a Table or as an image?
3. Example: I put a caption on the wrong position of the table, say on the bottom like the example above, and the paper is published.
   I after realize about the caption erroneous location. Is the paper subjected to a peer review again? Also, does that imply that **there should be** a review of the paper to properly position the caption in the correct location before being re-published?

Are there any official guidelines anyone can point me to answer those specific questions?

Thank you all for clarifying some of the doubts I have, and I am trying to be proactive and  make sure that everything is in the proper position since the beginning.

Comment: The IEEEtran manual says "Note that the IEEE places table captions
before the tables and, given that they serve much like titles,
are usually capitalized except for words such as a, an, and, as,
at, but, by, for, in, nor, of, on, or, the, to and up, which are
usually not capitalized unless they are the first or last word of
the caption."  And, yes, IEEE Xplore is published by IEEE (open access).

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo for stopping by and reading the question. What about the follow up points I mentioned in the question? In particular point 3) ?

Comment: I've never submitted to Xplore, but I would assume there is both peer and editor review as with all other IEEE publications.